# How to change nextIcon for antd DatePicker control

Tags: antd

I am using [antd Date picker](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/) control.

I need to change `nextIcon` and `superNextIcon` with customIcon.

I am trying as below, but its not changing the icon.

Help is much appreciated.

```
 <DatePicker
            superNextIcon={null}
            nextIcon={getIcon()}
            dropdownClassName="myBookingcalendar"
            className="displayFlex myBookingPicker"
            showToday={false}
            open
            dateRender={dateRender}
            style={{ visibility: 'hidden' }}
          />
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure why it was not working for you. But it works for me: https://codesandbox.io/embed/antd-reproduction-template-forked-stgo3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark. Maybe check your version?

Comment: Could you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?